# How to poll database using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I want to continuously poll a table from my database and push to Kafka.
I am using apache camel for this.

My routes are as follows:-

```
from(timer:every 1 sec).
to(sql:select first 1000 * from myTable where id > myId).
to(updateMyId).
to(kafka:url).end()
```

The problem is that it doesn't take the updated myId in the next iteration. The route is static and if initially myId = 1, then it keeps polling from 1.

How do I dynamically update myId?

Comment: What are you polling for? New rows? Updated rows? What is the database you are using?

Comment: Polling for new rows. Its a RDBMS, not fixed yet, could be MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.

Comment: I would like to poll for any new rows inserted for my oracle database. Can you please help me for the from and to part.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.set myId property as it gets updated.

```
   from(timer:every 1 sec).
   to(sql:select first 1000 * from myTable where id >:#${property.myId}).
   to(updateMyId).
   to(kafka:url).end();
```

Or move following logic to a bean.

```
   to(sql:select first 1000 * from myTable where id >:#${property.myId}).
   to(updateMyId).
```